# My page layout breaks in IE7, rights itself if I hover over/open a menu item

Tags: css, layout, internet-explorer-7, resize

As you can see if you go to the link below in IE7/AOL, the layout breaks if you resize the window.  However, click the `products` menu tab and it rights itself.  I haven't a clue why or how to fix it, and it looks sloppy.  On resizing the page, the logo and breadcrumb trail div stay where they ought to be, but my horizontal nav menu and everything below the breadcrumb div end up about 20-30 pixels off to the right. On refreshing the page, changing page, or opening a pull down menu item, it all falls back into the correct alignment.

[link text](http://sinaesthesia.co.uk)

Comment: Perhaps you could explain the layout issue you are having for us people not using IE7?

Comment: On resizing the page, the logo and breadcrumb trail div stay where they ought to be, but my horizontal nav menu and everything below the breadcrumb div end up about 20-30 pixels off to the right.  On refreshing the page, changing page, or opening a pull down menu item, it all falls back into the correct alignment.

Comment: Please keep this in your original question. You will have to explain what is ‘breaking’ because I don't see any unexpected behaviour in IE7 and clicking the menu tab doesn't change the layout at all. (Also, there is no such thing as “valid XHTML if you ignore the JavaScript”. Fix the script by putting it in a `//<![CDATA[`...`//]]>` block, or, better, kick the script out to an external file.)

Comment: The script is in an external file, but it is a .php5 file, as I use php's $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] in a JS function.  I have got rid of the script related validation errors now thanks to the CDATA block (I don't know why I didn't have those already), but did discover some more errors.  So, thanks :)

Comment: I'm not sure a -1 was necessary - I'm having a problem with layout, surely that is as valid as any other problem?  If I knew how to fix it I wouldn't have asked.  Sheesh.

Comment: I'm having this exact same problem. It's real.

Answer (score 0):

It is working as it should. The li elements in the menu are all floating to the available space. If the window does not have enough space they will float to the next available line. Nothing to see here.

Just use the CSS min-width to stop the DIV from becoming too small for the menu. Or consider a rigid layout (as oposed to a flexible one).

Add the following line to your div to make it work.

```
#outer {
    min-width:790px;
}
```

Comment: I already am turning it into a rigid layout if I detect IE7, and everything else works fine apart from these two things go out of alignment onresize.  I tried that line and it messed up several other things.

Answer (score 0):

To fix incorrectly rendered (in ie7) divs, which correct themselves after hovering over something else, mousing out, or any other weird event, use the below jQuery:

```
    if ($("html").hasClass("ie7")){
        var tempHolder = $("#ajaxresults").html();
        $("#ajaxresults").html(tempHolder);
    }
```

The logic is pretty simple, and I'm imagine you could do it just as easily with javascript's "innerHTML". Just rewrite the html contents of the div that's misbehaving, and this'll cause it to recompute the styles.

As for giving the html or body tag the ie7 class, I recommend taking a look at html5boilerplate.com. If for some reason you can't use their solution, the jquery for it is:

```
    if ($.browser.msie){
        if ($.browser.version < 8){
            $("html").addClass("ie ie7");
        }
        else {
            $("html").addClass("ie");
        }
    }
```

Comment: In another instance, I had to use a setTimeout with the above, because the browser took too long to do it's initial render.