# Offset in IE7 makes div misalign

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, offset

I've got a div which has a top-offset of 88, after the page makes a postback, the offset is changed to 225 and this makes the div misalign.

I've got another div, with the same css attributes which doesn't get this offset.

I've got no idea where does the offset is coming from or how could I remove it. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If you shared your code, it would be a lot easier to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend trying my answer from this post:

[My page layout breaks in IE7, rights itself if I hover over/open a menu item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526338/my-page-layout-breaks-in-ie7-rights-itself-if-i-hover-over-open-a-menu-item/4551220#4551220)